# custom header conditions APIM policy

Tags: azure

I m trying to implement a conditional flow where
if the `Consumer-Id` contains the value 1234 then it accepts and prints
but if `Consumer-Id` contains some other value like 4567 it throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the header value in the `when` policy:

`context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Consumer-Id") == "1234"`

For demonstration purpose, `return-response` is used in both cases.

Complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Consumer-Id") == "1234")">
                <return-response response-variable-name="res">
                    <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                    <set-body>@{
                        return context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Consumer-Id").ToString();
                    }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response response-variable-name="res">
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad request" />
                    <set-body>@{
                        return "Fail";
                    }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Header value `1234` returns http status code 200:

[image]

Incorrect header value produces an errorresponse:
[image]